# Order of SQL Query Clauses

Tags: mysql, sql

I ran into a situation where I don't seem to get what SQL is doing. I have the following table and want to give out all the sorts of coffee which have the most amount of rating=5 with the amount itself.

```
create table likes
(
     CName varchar(30),
     UName varchar(30),
     Rating int
);

insert into likes (CName, UName, Rating) 
values ('Java', 'Klaus', '5'),
       ('Super', 'Klaus', '5'),
       ('MP', 'Klaus', '3'),
       ('Java', 'Marc', '5'),
       ('Mp', 'Marc', '5'),
       ('Super', 'Marc', '2'),
       ('Java', 'Nine', '2'),
       ('Super', 'Nine', '0'),
       ('MP', 'Karo', '3'),
       ('Super', 'Fabian', '4');
```

However this solution doesn't work as intended

```
SELECT 
    favcof.CName, favcof.cnt
FROM 
   (SELECT l.CName, COUNT(CName) cnt
    FROM likes l
    WHERE l.rating = 5
    GROUP BY CName) favcof
WHERE 
    favcof.cnt = (SELECT MAX(favcof.cnt))
```

It executes as if there is no outer where-clause and gives out all sorts of  coffees with their amount of rating = 5.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Syntax error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `(select max(favcof.cnt))` doesn't do anything.  You can just drop the `select` and you will get `favcof.cnt = favcof.cnt`.

This is a little complicated, because `favcof.cnt = max(favcof.cnt)` would generate a syntax error because aggregation functions are not allowed in the `where` clause.  So, the `select` subquery is actually an aggregation subquery with no `from`.  Because there is only one value, it returns that value.

You want a correlated subquery.  This would look like:

```
SELECT favcof.CName, favcof.cnt
FROM (SELECT l.UName, count(UName) as cnt
      FROM likes l
      WHERE l.rating=5
      GROUP BY UName
     ) favcof
WHERE favcof.cnt = (SELECT MAX(favcof2.cnt)
                    FROM (SELECT l2.UName, count(l2.UName) as cnt
                          FROM likes l2
                          WHERE l2.rating=5
                          GROUP BY l2.UName
                         ) favcof2
                   );
```

There are definitely other ways to write this query.  However, this should help you understand why your version does not do what you want it to do.

Comment: Thanks! I had a solution like that but i do'nt get why
(select max(favcof.cnt))
does nothing.
I would expect it to select only the rows where cnt is max amount.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
DECLARE @likes AS TABLE(CName NVARCHAR(50), UName NVARCHAR(50), Rating INT)

insert into @likes (CName, UName, Rating) values
    ('Java', 'Klaus', '5'),
    ('Super', 'Klaus', '5'),
    ('MP', 'Klaus', '3'),
    ('Java', 'Marc', '5'),
    ('Mp', 'Marc', '5'),
    ('Super', 'Marc', '2'),
    ('Java', 'Nine', '2'),
    ('Super', 'Nine', '0'),
    ('MP', 'Karo', '3'),
    ('Super', 'Fabian', '4');

SELECT  UName, COUNT(CName) Cnt FROM @Likes
WHERE Rating = (SELECT MAX(Rating) FROM @Likes)
GROUP BY UNAME
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/MYIDJ19676)